# IndexError: expected dim 0 index in range [1, 3) Error Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, I am having strange error, where `a = [x[1], x[2]]` works, but `a = x[1:]` does not.

```
>>> out                                                                    
farray([Y[0], Y[1], Y[2]])                                                        
>>> out[1]
Y[1]
>>> remaining_out = [out[1], out[2]]
>>> remaining_out[0]
Y[1]
>>> remaining_out = out[1:]
>>> remaining_out[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
File "/home/kmshah4/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyeda/boolalg/bfarray.py", line 485, in __getitem__
nsls = self._norm_slices(fsls)                                                                                                                                        File "/home/kmshah4/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyeda/boolalg/bfarray.py", line 890, in _norm_slices                             nsls.append(_norm_index(i, fsl, *self.shape[i]))
File "/home/kmshah4/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyeda/boolalg/bfarray.py", line 1127, in _norm_index
raise IndexError(fstr.format(dim, start, stop))
IndexError: expected dim 0 index in range [1, 3)
```

Please help.

Comment: Does `farray` accept subscript notations? It does not seem to be a Python `list` type.

Comment: Some support might be found at this [Function Array](https://pyeda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/farray.html) website. That being said, without additional code and a description of your goal, you will not likely have many responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects in Python do not automatically support slice notation just because they support indexing. That has to be programmed in. There may be syntax more convenient than what you're using though.

If it's iterable, you can convert to a list first, and then slice it, like

```
a = [*x][1:]
```

For especially large iterables (does not seem to be the case here), this may be inefficient. In that case, `islice` it *before* you unpack into the list.

```
from itertools import islice
a = [*islice(x, 1, None)]
```

But objects do not automatically support iteration just because they support indexing either. If that's the case, you can still iterate manually with `range()` and a comprehension,

```
a = [x[i] for i in range(1, len(x))]
```

Though this isn't really shorter until you have a few more elements to deal with. If you need this pattern a lot you could abstract it into a function.

And finally, objects do not necessarily support `len` just because they support indexing. If you don't know the length in advance, about all you can do is loop through and catch the `LookupError` at that point.

Comment: It's the same as `[*x][1:]`, pretty much, just a bit more verbose. `list(x)` would still work on Python 2.7, but the `[*x]` syntax is newer.